# Security implications of "leaking" a file descriptor to a client

Tags: security, posix, file-descriptor, opc-ua

I am implementing the FileType object appendix of OPC UA part 5.

The spec specifies that a client can call the "open" method on a FileType object located in an OPC UA server. Open should return a handle that can be used in subsequent calls on that FileType object instance (read, write, close, etc...).
I am implementing that on a posix system. My implementation of the open method of the FileType object calls open() from the libc, which returns a file descriptor.

I now wonder if I can just use the file descriptor as a handle to pass to my client or if I should better generate some opaque handle to pass out (and map back to an fd in subsequent calls).

Are there security implications of "leaking" out such details of the server process?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a good idea as it allows clientA an educated guess about the handles used by clientB. The server needs to associate handles to their respective client session, but still... Feels like an accident waiting to happen.